# Apply class to every paragraph that holds image?

Tags: php, functions, filters

When adding an image to a page or post, Wordpress is automatically adding a paragraph tag `<p>` as parent holding the image. Like so:

```
<p><img src="my-image.jpg" alt=""></p>
```

Since there is no parent selector in CSS I'd love to find a solution to apply a specific classname to those paragraphs holding an actual image. The example above would thus result in:

```
<p class="my-class"><img src="my-image.jpg" alt=""></p>
```

Any idea if I can use `add_filter()` to apply a classname to each `p` that holds an image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use jQuery if you don't mind to rely on JavaScript for adding the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p:has(img)').addClass('image');
});
```

Update: the `.has()` method is probably faster, see this [jsperf.com test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-pseudo-selector-has-versus-method-has).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').has('img').addClass('image');
});
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need this to be a PHP solution. You could do something like this using 'the_content' filter. This will add the class name "content-img-wrap" to any paragraph that wraps only an image tag when Wordpress prints your post content. So this will not wrap a paragraph with an image and a span. See update if that is what your looking for.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'img_p_class_content_filter' ,20);
function img_p_class_content_filter($content) {
    // assuming you have created a page/post entitled 'debug'
    $content = preg_replace("/(<p)(>[^<]*<img[^>]+>[^<]*)(<\/p>)/i", "\$1 class='content-img-wrap'\$2\$3", $content);

    return $content;
}
```

** UPDATE BELOW: In response to the need for a more flexible wrap. I created and quickly tested this regex against 3 automatically wrapped paragraphs (meaning I didn't add the p tags, WP did) with images at the end of a post. They each also contained some random tags and carriage returns for testing likely cases and flexibility. The idea is that you don't have to match anything after the <img> because the presence of any <img> proves our case. Then we just add our custom class/es in (improvements more then welcome):

```
function img_p_class_content_filter($content) {
    // assuming you have created a page/post entitled 'debug'
    $content = preg_replace("/(<p[^>]*)(\>.*)(\<img.*)(<\/p>)/im", "\$1 class='content-img-wrap'\$2\$3\$4", $content);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: From taking a quick look at the regex, I think `[^<]*` is too narrow, as it would not consider span's occurring inside paragraphs.

Comment: @BramVanroy, I didn't even guessed that you can put a bounty on a question which is not your own. IMO you should ask a question as this one is resolved and I will be surprised if many people will bother reading it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun So you think I'd rather had written the exact same post again? It would've been marked as a duplicate I'm afraid.

Comment: @BramVanroy, yes it is awkward, but I don't know if you will be able to award the bounty at all and as I said most people probably do not look at resolved questions.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I+ can assign the bounty, not a problem. Also I think that a lot of people looking to get bounties look at bthe bounty category, so they'll find their way here.

Comment: @BramVanroy Honestly I was trying to be narrow. I thought the purpose was to hit p tags that wrap img tags, in which case this regular expression has some flexibility, but not enough to let another tag in. If that's what you need though it's an easy rewrite, just let me know, I've been busy so sorry for delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

While I understand wanting the front end to be as lean as possible and therefore stating you want a PHP solution...

- JS/jQuery is probably loaded on your front end already
- JS/jQuery is exactly designed for this use case (you already have an answer for that,
  which I have not tested)
- PHP REGEX is not an ideal way to handle
  this... further reading (follow its links) at
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664997/how-can-i-use-regular-expression-to-grab-an-img-tag#comment27488762_18664997

Personally, I spent quite a bit of time on this just for fun, and I kept coming up with ways to break the regex matching (hence, why not to use PHP without a library add-on specifically designed to traverse HTML, as mentioned in the link above)...

For example:
[image]

This screenshot's rule will match `<p>` or even `<P   >` (the simplest match, not trying yet for P tags that already have a class or have other attributes but not a class), but see that it has to be matched WITHIN the entire block of closing tags (where PHP regex for HTML falls apart at the seams)... the arrow points to where a closing P tag and opening P tag are on the same line and therefore if you were to count this as a FIND and then replace the `<p` with `<p class="my-class"`, you'd be adding `my-class` to the wrong paragraph.

If you didn't want such an "every scenario" use case, it's doable via regex. If you narrow your scope a bit.

If you decide to limit your scope, you might be interested in this information:

```
    From wp-includes/default-filters.php
    these run on the_content with default priority (10):
        wptexturize
        convert_smilies
        convert_chars
        wpautop
        shortcode_unautop
        prepend_attachment
    shortcode renders may add new paragraphs and/or new images
        do_shortcode runs on the_content priority 11 so we hook in afterwards so $content already has shortcodes rendered
*/
add_filter('the_content', 'se_16033', 15); //a priority higher than 11
```

Here's some starting code if you do force yourself down this complicated route (instead of via jQuery):

```
    function se_16033($content) {
    if( !is_singular() || !is_main_query() //https://pippinsplugins.com/playing-nice-with-the-content-filter/
    ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $content = force_balance_tags($content); //We do not want to be REGEXing on unbalanced HTML tags so we must make sure they are balanced before we get started -- garbage in, worse garbage out -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#HTML

    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/quick/'; //first match p tags with existing classes because we just want to add an additional class
    $patterns[1] = '/brown/'; //second, match p tags with space (e.g. style) but without class=""
    $patterns[2] = '/fox/'; //third, match <p> tags without attributes
    ksort($patterns);

    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = 'slow';
    $replacements[1] = 'black';
    $replacements[2] = 'bear';
    ksort($replacements);

    preg_replace_all($patterns, $replacements, $content);

    return $content;

}
```

Note the use of http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags
By default, it gets used on the Excerpt and Comments
If you look at its source, it actually uses REGEX: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1453

SIDENOTE
I assume the reason they *fallback* (not ideal) to using REGEX is because of WP's need to run on almost any host's PHP configuration imaginable (i.e. not wanting to load a library in case that PHP extension is disabled). You could choose to load a PHP library designed to do this in your own solution.
/SIDENOTE

It's a whole lot of code to be ran every time `is_singular()`. As such, I'm not sure it'd be worth it to use as inspiration for some complex PHP solution when your site is likely already using JS/jQuery.

- Is this P class somehow needing to work even on non-JS-enabled browsers?
- Are you an über-performance guru? If yes, do you have any jQuery in use on your site currently (e.g. slider, motion, etc)? If yes, the minimalistic jQuery needed to do this is not going to add bloat. Just go with it.
- If you do NOT have jQuery loaded on front-end, we could come up with a pure JavaScript way to accomplish this (i.e. not via jQuery)

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses the `autop` function to add `<p></p>` to line breaks in your content.

The autop function can be found on line 373 in [formatting.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/formatting.php). An option is to disable the default autop (see below), create a new version of the function adding your class, and then apply it to your content (see the link below for that too). I guess you'd be adding a regex around line 442 to do that.

If you just want to remove the effect of the paragraph you can disable `autop` like this:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Which can be found on the [autop page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter):

Comment: not going to downvote, but messing up with autop is a very dangerous thing, and it will not solve the case where the html is generated by a shortcode.

Comment: I'm not suggesting messing with autop, I'm suggesting creating a custom function based on autop, which is completely ok, and not dangerous.

I don't see shortcode mentioned in the question.

Comment: which is exactly the same as messing with autop, and you don't see spans and links mentioned as well....

Comment: If writing a custom function is called 'messing' then I guess you're right.

Comment: yes, removing core functionality and replacing it with your own is "messing"

Comment: autop is optional, if you see the answer you'll see a reference to removing autop provided by Wordpress.

Wordpress is built to be flexible and allow developers to modify it's behaviour for custom needs. This is one of them.

If I were suggesting touching the core files you'd have a point, but as I'm not, you don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20981/discussion-between-shahar-and-mark-kaplun).